# For loop regression

Tags: r, loops

Looking to try and carry out a loop regression. I will explain as best as I can the set up.

I have a vector `X1` and `A` which are fixed lets say (they do not change/update)

I have 5 data.frame called `df1, df2, df3, df4, df5`. Which consists of `col1, col2, col3, col4, col5`.

What I am trying to do is run a regression model which will read something along the lines;

```
Read in df(1), col(1)
Compute Y: data(1) - A     # Or df1$col1 - A 
Run OLS regressed Y on X1
Store results in new.data.frame

Read in df(1), col(2)
Compute Y: data(2) - A        # This time df1$col2
Run OLS regressed Y on X1
Store results in new.data.frame

.....

# Do until df(1), col(5) 

.....

Then;

Read in df(2), col(1)
Compute Y: data(6) - A    # Which will now be df2$col1
Run OLS
Store results in new.data.frame
```

.....

```
Do this until df(2), col(5) as before
Complete up until df(5), col(5).
```

I will paste my small code which does not work, but if you can give me any pointers how I can run this loop that would be great.

```
    data <- NULL
    for(i in 1:5) {
      data[i] <- df1$col1
      Y <- data[i] - A
      print(Y)
      model <- lm(Y ~ X1)
    }
```

I provide some test code so that you can get an idea of the stucture of the df

```
col1 = c(2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3) 
col2 = c(4, 8, 1, 3, 1, 4, 6) 
col3 = c(1, 9, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8) 
col4 = c(1, 9, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8) 
col5 = c(1, 9, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8) 
df1 = data.frame(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) 

df1

col1 = c(8, 5, 3, 2, 3, 5, 2) 
col2 = c(4, 8, 1, 3, 1, 4, 6) 
col3 = c(1, 9, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8) 
col4 = c(1, 9, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8) 
col2 = c(4, 8, 1, 3, 1, 4, 6) 
df2 = data.frame(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) 

df2

A <- c(9, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 6)
X1 <- c(0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.1)
```

Comment: What results from your call to `lm` do you want to store in a dataframe?

Comment: Ah apologies I did not state, at the moment I am just interested in the coefficiant value for X1 - I can add further results myself later.

Answer (score 0):

No loops necessary.

Not sure if you  need to keep the dataframes separate, but because the results are going into the same dataframe, just bind all the data frames together:

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c(2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3), 
              col2 = c(4, 8, 1, 3, 1, 4, 6), 
              col3 = c(1, 9, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8), 
              col4 = c(1, 9, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8), 
              col5 = c(1, 9, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8))

df2 <- data.frame(col1 = c(8, 5, 3, 2, 3, 5, 2),
                  col2 = c(4, 8, 1, 3, 1, 4, 6), 
                  col3 = c(1, 9, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8), 
                  col4 = c(1, 9, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8), 
                  col5 = c(4, 8, 1, 3, 1, 4, 6))

A <- c(9, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 6)
X1 <- c(0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.1)

all_dfs <- bind_cols(df1, df2)
```

Now a function that takes a column, calculates the y, runs the regression, and returns the `X1` coefficient:

```
foo <- function(col){

    y <- col - A
    mod <- lm(y~X1)
    return(mod$coefficients[2])
}
```

Apply the function to all of the columns in the big dataframe and convert to a dataframe

```
sapply(all_dfs, foo) %>% as.data.frame()

> sapply(all_dfs, foo) %>% as.data.frame()
                  .
col1.X1   -3.382353
col2.X1  -10.220588
col3.X1   -5.661765
col4.X1   -5.661765
col5.X1   -5.661765
col11.X1  -1.838235
col21.X1 -10.220588
col31.X1  -5.661765
col41.X1  -5.661765
col51.X1 -10.220588
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution I really appreciate it. I have applied it to the dataset I am currently working on, but I am only able to obtain a coefficient for the first regression ran. I get an output of col1...col11,...,col51 all of the same number. I am getting lost with how I can apply the function to all the columns in the big dataframe

Comment: I get col1 1.43, col2 1.43, col3 1.43, col4 1.43, col5 1.43, col 11 1.43 etc

Comment: I see where I am going wrong. It is in regards to the variable creation of Y. I have; `var1 <- df1$col1` then I have `Y <- var1 - A` which does not update or move to `df1$col2` - I will have a little think, thank you for the code its very useful.